# Did I post a comment on this answer?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments

Many times I *intend* to post something, even plan it out in my mind. Sometimes I make a draft in my editor first. Still, I get distracted and forget to post my comment from time to time. Until now I've been able to tell if I *really* commented, or merely planned to, by reviewing the question from my favorites tab, and either finding my comment, or seeing that it's not there and knowing I still have to take the final step and actually post it.

An answer [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4420/207673) is one I am almost certain that I commented on, and I think I even got a response to it. The reverse logic around the OP's use of a quote from R. Stallman is what sticks in my mind. Admittedly my ancient, code addled brain has some bad sectors in it, yet I'm sure the comment *was* posted.

The only thing I can think of is that my comment was deleted, along with the response to it, by someone with that power. (A mod, maybe high-rep user, not sure, and it don't matter.) I *think* I recall a much larger list of comments than is currently there as well. Anyway, since I can't see any remnants of my comment in my profile page, on the question page, or in my inbox, can someone tell me if I really did post the comment, and it later got deleted?

I don't care if it was deleted as part of the site's upkeep. That's a legitimate process for the good of the site. I just want to know if my mind is developing more bad sectors, or not.

Comment: The answer has been downvoted into oblivion (-4), so low rep users won't see it, or the comments attached to it. Yours is still there.

Comment: @jasonwryan I actually changed things in the last minute or two, sorry. I'm posting an explanation now

Comment: @jasonwryan Considering that user's attitude to the site's normal operation, oblivion is probably where the answer (comment more likely) belongs anyway. But knowing I _did_ post my comment is reassuring.

Comment: BTW, @jasonwryan, am I seeing the oblivioned post because I have a comment on it, or because I have a direct link, or just because I'm paying attention to the "ghost" text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments can be deleted by the people who posted them as well as moderators, but in this case it was actually an entirely different answer. The author deleted the existing answer and posted an almost identical answer all within a few seconds, I assume because the first answer had several downvotes.

I restored the [original answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4419/73), moved the comments the new answer had gotten onto it so they're all in one place, and deleted the new answer you were seeing

Comment: ¡Ay, caramba! Oblivion may be too good for that half-answer after all. Anyway, now I _do_ see my comment, and it's ...rebuttal? Thanks for the info too. I never would've thought of that tactic. Don't plan to use it either, to weird for my tastes.  (_Oh, the joys of being a mod._)